# Number of touches shows 1 after the first touch

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, touches

I'm using Cocos2D for my game development. Here's what I've come across recently.

```
-(void)ccTouchesBegan:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event{
      NSLog(@"Number of touches %d",touches.count);
}
```

I run my sample app on iPod touch and touch the screen with my two fingers. The first time I touch, the log shows "Number of touches 2" but after the first touch I get "Number of touches 1" no matter how many fingers I touch with.

I also have a problem with the tap count too. If I NSLog the tap count and touch the screen I  get the following output:

```
The tap count is 1
The tap count is 2
The tap count is 3 
And so on.....
```

Shouldn't I get only "The tap count 3" when I triple tap the screen instead of getting 1,2,3? It registers all the taps until the last one.

What I know and am sure about touches is:

1. Touch can be single or multi-touch depending on the fingers tapping the screen.
2. Touch has a tap count property that can be 1 or higher.

I need these two behaviors to work properly because I'll decide what to do depending on the number of touches and taps.

Answer (score 2):

```
NSArray * touchArray = [touches allObjects];
NSLog(@"Number of touches %d",touchArray.count);
```

the above code is how many touches are currently active if you do

```
NSSet *touches= [event allTouches];
```

you will get a count of how many touches at once triggered the method as in a two finger tap or three finger tap

Comment: This really helped with the number of touches. But I don't get one thing: What's the difference between counting the objects in an NSSet and putting all the objects in it into an NSArray and then count that array?

Comment: hope this helps you can see that they use a nsuinteger for tap count within the method http://www.techotopia.com/index.php/An_Example_iOS_4_iPhone_Touch,_Multitouch_and_Tap_Application

Comment: @MikeJM and in response to your question on the difference between using Apples NSSet method and creating your own array, to be honest i would have written it exactly as you originally did because it looks like it should work but i looked it up and saw multiple others using their own array without issue. Just to be sure even though you may have it make sure your view has the allows user interaction and multitouch enable check boxes in storyboard selected.